# React Context is updated but the components aren't rendering the changes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context, provider

I am trying to use Context API with hooks in part of our project at the company. We use typescript. I created a Context, a Provider and a Reducer. When I click buttons, the state changes but the components don't render the changes. I've created a mini replica version of the thing that I am implementing and still couldn't figure out.

What am I doing wrong?

**App.tsx**:

```
import './App.css';
import { PlayerGameDataProvider } from './State/UserContext';
import GamesList from './Components/GamesList';

function App() {
  return (
    <PlayerGameDataProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <GamesList />
        </header>
      </div>
    </PlayerGameDataProvider>

  );
}

export default App;
```

**UserContext.tsx**

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react"

export enum ActionType {
  Accept = 'ACCEPTED',
  Reject = 'REJECTED',
}

export enum ResponseState {
  Accepted = 'ACCEPTED',
  Rejected = 'REJECTED',
  Pending = 'PENDING',
}

export enum GameState {
  Ongoing = 'ONGOING',
  Upcoming = 'UPCOMING',
  Finished = 'FINISHED',
}

export interface IGameStatus {
  id: number,
  name:string,
  response: ResponseState,
  state: GameState,
}

export interface IPlayerResponseData {
  type: ActionType,
  payload: any,
}

export interface IPlayerGameData {
  playerId: number,
  games: IGameStatus[],
}

const setPlayerResponse = (state:IPlayerGameData, action: IPlayerResponseData) => {
  const filtered:any = state.games.filter((game:any) => game.id === action.payload.tournamentId);
  filtered[0].response = action.type;
  return filtered;
}

export const PlayerTournamentResponseAction = (state: IPlayerGameData, action: IPlayerResponseData):any => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionType.Accept:
      return {
        ...state,
        games: setPlayerResponse(state, action),
      }
    case ActionType.Reject:
      return {
        ...state,
        games: setPlayerResponse(state, action),
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const InitGame = ():IPlayerGameData => {
  return {
    playerId: 12345,
    games: [
      {
        id:0,
        name: "Game 1",
        response: ResponseState.Accepted,
        state: GameState.Ongoing,
      },
      {
        id:1,
        name: "Game 2",
        response: ResponseState.Pending,
        state: GameState.Ongoing,
      },
      {
        id:2,
        name: "Game 3",
        response: ResponseState.Pending,
        state: GameState.Ongoing,
      },
      {
        id:3,
        name: "Game 4",
        response: ResponseState.Pending,
        state: GameState.Upcoming,
      },
      {
        id:4,
        name: "Game 5",
        response: ResponseState.Pending,
        state: GameState.Upcoming,
      },
      {
        id:5,
        name: "Game 6",
        response: ResponseState.Rejected,
        state: GameState.Finished,
      },
      {
        id:6,
        name: "Game 7",
        response: ResponseState.Accepted,
        state: GameState.Finished,
      }
    ]
  }
}

const initialData:IPlayerGameData = InitGame();

export const PlayerContext = createContext<IPlayerGameData[]>([initialData]);

export const PlayerGameDataProvider = (props:any) => {
  const [data, setData] = useReducer(PlayerTournamentResponseAction, initialData);

  return <PlayerContext.Provider value={[data, setData]}>{props.children}</PlayerContext.Provider>
}
```

**GamesList.tsx**

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { PlayerContext } from "../State/UserContext";
import GameElement from "./GameElement";

const GamesList = (props: any) => {
  const [data, setData] = useContext(PlayerContext);
  useEffect(() => {

  }, [data])
  const gameListObjects = data.games.map((game:any)=> {
    return <GameElement id={game.id} name={game.name} state={game.state} response={game.response}/>
  });

  return (
    <div>
    {gameListObjects} 
    </div>
  )
}

export default GamesList;
```

**GameElement.tsx**

```
import { useContext, useReducer } from "react";
import { ActionType, PlayerContext, PlayerTournamentResponseAction } from "../State/UserContext";

const GameElement = (props:any) => {
  const [data, setData] = useContext(PlayerContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <dt>
          GameID: {props.id}
        </dt>
        <dt>
          Game Name: {props.name}
        </dt>
        <dt>
          Game Status: {props.state}
        </dt>
        <dt>
          Player Response: {props.response}
        </dt>
        <dt>
          <button onClick = {() => PlayerTournamentResponseAction(data, {type:ActionType.Accept, payload: {tournamentId: props.id}})}>Accept</button>
          <button onClick = {() => PlayerTournamentResponseAction(data, {type:ActionType.Reject, payload: {tournamentId: props.id}})}>Reject</button>
        </dt>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
  )
}

export default GameElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call the redux reducer function in the event handler directly, instead, we should use the `dispatch` function returned by the `useReducer` hook to update the state. So that the `PlayerGameDataProvider` component will re-render after the state changes.

You are trying to get the React context in the `GameElement` component, this makes the component stateful, not pure. Increases complexity and reduces maintainability. A better way is to make the `GameElement` component pure. We can expose the `onAccept()` and `onReject()` functions for it.

I also improve the TS types. Now, let's see the complete code:

`App.tsx`:

```
import { PlayerGameDataProvider } from './UserContext';
import GamesList from './GamesList';
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <PlayerGameDataProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <GamesList />
        </header>
      </div>
    </PlayerGameDataProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`UseContext.tsx`:

```
import React, { createContext, Dispatch, ReducerAction, useReducer } from 'react';

export enum ActionType {
  Accept = 'ACCEPTED',
  Reject = 'REJECTED',
}

export enum ResponseState {
  Accepted = 'ACCEPTED',
  Rejected = 'REJECTED',
  Pending = 'PENDING',
}

export enum GameState {
  Ongoing = 'ONGOING',
  Upcoming = 'UPCOMING',
  Finished = 'FINISHED',
}

export interface IGameStatus {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  response: ResponseState;
  state: GameState;
}

export interface IPlayerResponseData {
  type: ActionType;
  payload: {
    tournamentId: number;
    response: ResponseState;
  };
}

export interface IPlayerGameData {
  playerId: number;
  games: IGameStatus[];
}

const setPlayerResponse = (state: IPlayerGameData, action: IPlayerResponseData) => {
  return state.games.map((game) =>
    game.id === action.payload.tournamentId ? { ...game, response: action.payload.response } : game
  );
};

export const PlayerTournamentResponseReducer = (state: IPlayerGameData, action: IPlayerResponseData) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionType.Accept:
      return {
        ...state,
        games: setPlayerResponse(state, action),
      };
    case ActionType.Reject:
      return {
        ...state,
        games: setPlayerResponse(state, action),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const InitGame = (): IPlayerGameData => {
  return {
    playerId: 12345,
    games: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: 'Game 1',
        response: ResponseState.Accepted,
        state: GameState.Ongoing,
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Game 2',
        response: ResponseState.Pending,
        state: GameState.Ongoing,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Game 3',
        response: ResponseState.Pending,
        state: GameState.Ongoing,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Game 4',
        response: ResponseState.Pending,
        state: GameState.Upcoming,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Game 5',
        response: ResponseState.Pending,
        state: GameState.Upcoming,
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Game 6',
        response: ResponseState.Rejected,
        state: GameState.Finished,
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Game 7',
        response: ResponseState.Accepted,
        state: GameState.Finished,
      },
    ],
  };
};

const initialData: IPlayerGameData = InitGame();

export const PlayerContext = createContext<
  [IPlayerGameData, Dispatch<ReducerAction<typeof PlayerTournamentResponseReducer>>]
>([initialData, () => {}]);

export const PlayerGameDataProvider = (props: React.PropsWithChildren<{}>) => {
  const [data, dispatch] = useReducer(PlayerTournamentResponseReducer, initialData);

  return <PlayerContext.Provider value={[data, dispatch]}>{props.children}</PlayerContext.Provider>;
};
```

`GamesList.tsx`:

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { ActionType, PlayerContext, ResponseState } from './UserContext';
import GameElement from './GameElement';
import React from 'react';

const GamesList = () => {
  const [data, dispatch] = useContext(PlayerContext);
  console.log(' ~ file: GamesList.tsx:8 ~ GamesList ~ data:', data);
  const gameListObjects = data.games.map((game) => {
    return (
      <GameElement
        key={game.id}
        id={game.id}
        name={game.name}
        state={game.state}
        response={game.response}
        onAccept={() =>
          dispatch({ type: ActionType.Accept, payload: { tournamentId: game.id, response: ResponseState.Accepted } })
        }
        onReject={() =>
          dispatch({ type: ActionType.Reject, payload: { tournamentId: game.id, response: ResponseState.Rejected } })
        }
      />
    );
  });
  return <div>{gameListObjects}</div>;
};

export default GamesList;
```

`GameElement.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export type GameElementProps = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  state: string;
  response: string;
  onAccept(): void;
  onReject(): void;
};
const GameElement = (props: GameElementProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <dt>GameID: {props.id}</dt>
        <dt>Game Name: {props.name}</dt>
        <dt>Game Status: {props.state}</dt>
        <dt>Player Response: {props.response}</dt>
        <dt>
          <button onClick={props.onAccept}>Accept</button>
          <button onClick={props.onReject}>Reject</button>
        </dt>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GameElement;
```

`App.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { fireEvent, render, screen, within } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

describe('76015456', () => {
  test('should switch the response of the game to accepted', (done) => {
    render(<App />);
    const ulist = screen.getByText('GameID: 1').parentElement;
    if (!ulist) return done('can not find game with ID:1');
    const acceptButton = within(ulist).getByText('Accept');
    fireEvent.click(acceptButton);
    done();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76015456/App.test.tsx (8.39 s)
  76015456
    ✓ should pass (70 ms)

  console.log
     ~ file: GamesList.tsx:8 ~ GamesList ~ data: {
      playerId: 12345,
      games: [
        { id: 0, name: 'Game 1', response: 'ACCEPTED', state: 'ONGOING' },
        { id: 1, name: 'Game 2', response: 'PENDING', state: 'ONGOING' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Game 3', response: 'PENDING', state: 'ONGOING' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Game 4', response: 'PENDING', state: 'UPCOMING' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Game 5', response: 'PENDING', state: 'UPCOMING' },
        { id: 5, name: 'Game 6', response: 'REJECTED', state: 'FINISHED' },
        { id: 6, name: 'Game 7', response: 'ACCEPTED', state: 'FINISHED' }
      ]
    }

      at GamesList (stackoverflow/76015456/GamesList.tsx:8:11)

  console.log
     ~ file: GamesList.tsx:8 ~ GamesList ~ data: {
      playerId: 12345,
      games: [
        { id: 0, name: 'Game 1', response: 'ACCEPTED', state: 'ONGOING' },
        { id: 1, name: 'Game 2', response: 'ACCEPTED', state: 'ONGOING' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Game 3', response: 'PENDING', state: 'ONGOING' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Game 4', response: 'PENDING', state: 'UPCOMING' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Game 5', response: 'PENDING', state: 'UPCOMING' },
        { id: 5, name: 'Game 6', response: 'REJECTED', state: 'FINISHED' },
        { id: 6, name: 'Game 7', response: 'ACCEPTED', state: 'FINISHED' }
      ]
    }

      at GamesList (stackoverflow/76015456/GamesList.tsx:8:11)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.863 s
```

We click the "Accept" button for the game with ID: 1. As you can see, the value of the `response` field switched to `'ACCEPTED'` from `'PENDING'`.